# How to import UML based Web Engineering "UWE" profile into enterprise architect?

Tags: web, uml, enterprise-architect, magic-draw

is there any way to import UWE Profile into EA? actually its profile is exported using MagicDraw UML CASE tool, i've tried to import it but it is giving me parsing error when i do? 
this's the official site of UWE  http://uwe.pst.ifi.lmu.de/publicationsMetamodelAndProfile.html  
any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. UML profiles have no standardized external representation like models do (and even in that case, the standard is too weak to be useful), and profile formats are proprietary in each tool. Unless you can find a specialized third-party profile conversion tool, moving profiles between modelling tools isn't possible.